# How to change colour of dataDetectorType link in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, datadetectortypes

I want to change all dataDetectorType Colour in UIWebView including PhoneNo , emailID , Calendar and every dataDetctorType. I also need Tappable link for that dataDetector link.

Comment: Post your code showing what you have attempt so far.

Comment: just change the tintcolor and check once

Answer (score 4):

Adding some CSS to set the link color works, but for auto-detected links and e-mails etc it is necessary to add `!important` for the color to be applied.

`<style>a { color: red !important; }</style>`

Comment: This did the trick fro me.

Answer (score 1):

For UITextView, you can use linkTextAttributes for this, but there is no such thing for UIWebView. You will have to add CSS to the content you are loading to style the automatically inserted A tags.

Answer (score 0):

CSS example to change the detected link color:

```
NSString *html = @"<style>a:link { color: red; }</style> <h3>detected phone number: 111122223333</h3> <a href='www.google.com'>google link</a>";
[webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

The result in WebView:
[image]